# Interactive subprocess in Python 3 appears to continue with no input to its stdin stream

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been attempting to write a wrapper program around Spike's interactive debug mode on (https://github.com/riscv-software-src/riscv-isa-sim) in Python 3 to provide additional functionality that is not present in the base program. I have Spike running on a Debian system in WSL.

Typically, a session in Spike's interactive debugger looks as follows:

```
(spike) pc 0
0x0000000000001000
(spike)
core   0: 0x0000000000001000 (0x00000297) auipc   t0, 0x0
(spike) quit
```

Where the text after (spike) is user input, and a blank afterwards just means enter was pressed immediately.

The problem arises when I attempt to run the program through Python's subprocess Popen object. I first used the following code to make sure that the process was booting correctly (the script is running in the same folder as a.out and spike is on the system path):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

spike = Popen(["spike", "-d", "a.out"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(spike.poll())

spike.terminate()
```

Which worked as expected with the poll call returning `None`. However, when I ran a test script, it produced some unexpected output. The test script follows:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

spike = Popen(["spike", "-d", "a.out"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

spike.stdin.write(b"pc 0\n")
spike.stdin.flush()
print(spike.stdout.readline())

spike.stdin.close()
spike.terminate()
```

And the output: `b'(spike) core   0: 0x0000000000001000 (0x00000297) auipc   t0, 0x0\n'`.
This is the output for when you just press enter immediately after getting the prompt, not for the given command `pc 0`. I then ran an intentionally flawed program (that normally should hang) to see if my input was even being registered:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

spike = Popen(["spike", "-d", "a.out"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

print(spike.stdout.readline())
print(spike.stdout.readline())

spike.terminate()
```

And to my surprise it worked perfectly fine without hanging, producing the following:

```
b'(spike) core   0: 0x0000000000001000 (0x00000297) auipc   t0, 0x0\n'
b'(spike) core   0: 0x0000000000001004 (0x02028593) addi    a1, t0, 32\n'
```

I am fairly inexperienced with the Python subprocess module, but I believe that with the last script stdin should have been completely empty, meaning that a call to read from it would just hang. However, it seems like Spike does not care at all about it being empty, and just continues on its merry way. My question is as to how I can fix this such that Spike will wait on the script sending in input, instead of just taking the empty stream to mean that enter was pressed?